# How to generate only Hibernate Envers Audit Tables

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-envers

I know that hbm2ddl will generate the _aud tables for Hibernate Envers.

The problem is, that it also creates all other tables but I don't want to have that. I only need the _aud tables.

Is there a way to achieve that?